# DispatchQueue main isn't called

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have an async task o perform the calculation and the animation, as the animation begins, the queue suspends, when the animation finishes, the queue is resumed. But for some reason the DispatchQueue.main.sync is never called.

```
self.someQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "Animation", qos: .background, attributes: DispatchQueue.Attributes.concurrent)
    for index in stride(from: volumeObjects.count, to: -1, by: -1) {
        mainAsyncQueue.sync{
            self.dynamicViewModel.currentPercentile = Float(index)/Float(volumeObjects.count)
            self.currentObjectIndex = index
            print(index)

            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                    self.updateViewModelDynamicViewModel()
                }, completion: { (finished) in
                    self.someQueue.resume()
                })
            }
            self.someQueue.suspend()
        }
    }
```

This is just small calculation, I'll use that to solve tasks more complex than that

Comment: I don't see any *async* task. `mainAsyncQueue` is actually `backgroundSyncQueue` ;)

Comment: Ok variable name Nazi :P Changing it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume this code is in the main thread.

If so, you have sync'd to a background thread and from there tried to sync back to `DispatchQueue.main`.  But that queue is waiting for the background one to return before it can do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Lou Franco's answer I did some changes:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
            self.someQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "Animation", qos: .background, attributes: DispatchQueue.Attributes.concurrent)
            for index in stride(from: volumeObjects.count, to: -1, by: -1) {
                self.someQueue.sync{
                    self.dynamicViewModel.currentPercentile = Float(index)/Float(volumeObjects.count)
                    self.currentObjectIndex = index
                    print(index)

                    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                            self.updateViewModelDynamicViewModel()
                        }, completion: { (finished) in
                            if finished {
                                self.someQueue.resume()
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    self.someQueue.suspend()
                }
            }
        }
```